# How can I put the MPMediaPickerController cancel button on left side?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mpmediapickercontroller, ios

I'm developing an app and so far all cancel buttons have been on the left side of the navigation item. I thought this was standard and that's what Apple do with their apps. That is until I ran into the MPMediaPickerController which has it's cancel button on the right side of the navigation item.

Is there anyway I can move this to the left side? I'm reluctant to move all my other cancel buttons to the right as no other apps have this. But having it switch sides from one view to the next is even worse.

Annoyingly, the docs for the MPMediaPickerController adds this:

> Notes: The MPMediaPickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class does support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private; do not modify the view hierarchy.

I'm in no great hurry to release this app so I'm willing to risk rejection for moving this button if I can as it will vastly improve the user experience.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this and had to change my user interface in other areas.